# Is there any endpoint of NSE API which gives Technical Indicators as JSON output?

Tags: api, stock, stockquotes

I have been using https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=ABB endpoint for getting basic details of a stock symbol.

I have requirement of Technical Indicators such as RSI, MACD etc. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.